# how to stop heroku from restarting dynos

Tags: node.js, heroku, cron

I have a `node.js` app hosted on `Heroku`. I am paying the $7 a month hosting for the better plan which has me running with the next tier dynos and SSL. My problem is, I have a `cronjob` running in my app that runs every minute. It is VERY important this runs every minute and pretty much never misses. However, it happens to not run sometimes, and after debugging a little bit, I believe it to be that it restarts itself. like so:

[image]

So I was wondering if there is a way to schedule the app to restart instead of having it do it whenever, or if my cronjob is actually the problem and I can't do what I'm looking for. any ideas?

**EDIT**: here's the `cronjob` code:

```
var sendTexts = new CronJob('*/1 * * * *', function() {
// code that sends Texts if event is true
}, null, true)
```

and it should run every 1 minute. it does locally when my server is up, but again the issue seems to be with restarting dynos

Comment: You cannot prevent dynos from restarting. They are disposable and restarted frequently as a fundamental part of Heroku's architectural design.

Comment: But that might not matter. How are you running your scheduled job? Do you have a [clock process](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/scheduled-jobs-custom-clock-processes#custom-clock-processes)?

Comment: @Chris good to know, thanks. I don't have clock process, never seen that before! But i added some code to show what I am doing with a little explanation, please see above :)

Comment: @Chris i was also thinking to actually make the function a route, and have a 3rd party ping that specific route every minute. Maybe that would fix it? Not sure if you have any thoughts on that?

Comment: Relying on an outside service to hit your app every minute isn't the solution. If you intend to stay on Heroku, I strongly suggest you look into clock processes. Though, now we're back at your own code running all the time and determining when to run a task, which you claim doesn't work. What makes you think Heroku's dyno restarts are the cause of your missed jobs?

Comment: @Chris at the top of every hour, heroku process says it changes from `starting to up`. and it doesn't run the cronjob for that minute. but then once (ex) `10:01` rolls around, it runs. So i think I am just going to send out the text 1 minute before or 1 minute after.

Answer (score 0):

Dynos are restarted (cycled) at least every 24 hours, if you restart manually (with `heroku` CLI for example) will reset the 24 hour period.
You could consider restarting you app every X hours to try to manage that, however you must consider:

- Dynos can be restarted randomly by Heroku (after a platform error)
- upon restart your chronojob starts immediately, so you are going to have executions before a whole minute is passed

You might want to consider an architectural change using a DB or a queue which allow you not to rely on the application always running.
In cloud-based architecture it is never a good idea to assume a single instance (container) is always available.